# entity that has null value should be last entity after sorting by using order by in c#

Tags: c#, list, linq, sorting, null

I have a list and I want to sort it by "sortOrder" with using Linq(order by method), some on my entities in my list have null value for "sortOrder" property and I want to sort them with this rule: every entity that has null value in "sortOrder" property, will be in last index of my list(i don't care about how many entities can have null value and i don't care about sorting between entities with null value)

this is my code:

```
myList.Select(Map).OrderBy(a => a.SortOrder).ToList();
```

this is the result:

```
[
  {
    "SortOrder": null
  },
  {
    "SortOrder" : 2
  }
]
```

but this is what I want and I don't know how to implement it:

```
[
  {
    "SortOrder": 2
  },
  {
    "SortOrder" : null
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a trick like the one below.

```
List<MyEntity> myList = new List<MyEntity>
{
    new MyEntity { SortOrder = 2 },
    new MyEntity { SortOrder = null },
    new MyEntity { SortOrder = 1 },
};


List<MyEntity> sortedList = myList.OrderBy(e => e.SortOrder ?? int.MaxValue).ToList();
```

Comment: I did ,sites didn't let me to do at first

Answer (score 2):

While the answer by @VivekNuna works and is probably the simplest, the more idiomatic way to do it is to use a custom comparer.

```cs
var comparer = Comparer<YourMapClass>.Create((a, b) =>
    a.SortOrder.HasValue
    ? b.SortOrder.HasValue
      ? a.SortOrder.Value.CompareTo(b.SortOrder.Value)
      : -1
    : 1
);
```

```
myList
  .Select(Map)
  .Order(comparer)
  .ToList();
```

Or to sort the same list

```cs
myList.Sort(comparer);
```

You can alternatively create a comparer for `int?`

```cs
var comparer = Comparer<int?>.Create((a, b) =>
    a.HasValue
    ? b.HasValue
      ? a.Value.CompareTo(b.Value)
      : -1
    : 1
);
```

And do

```
myList
  .Select(Map)
  .OrderBy(e => e.SortOrder, comparer)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: thanks it's cool to to these stuff